# Multi-broker Confluent Kafka docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

A while back I needed to instantiate a multi-broker `Confluent Kafka` stack using `Confluent`'s docker images and `docker-compose(1)`. Although `Confluent`s documentation is quite excellent, it only offers a `single-broker` `docker-compose.yml` example; but not, say, a `three-broker` example from which one could study the pattern and generalize to any number of brokers needed. I pieced the `three-broker` version myself.

Sadly, I lost the result and had to manually re-create that again today. Web searches for this aren't great, so I'll memorialize the result as an answer to this question (for others).

Following is (more or less) the original `single-broker` file which you can obtain [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/6.2.1-post/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml). I added a static network (called `verilabs`) and removed two unneeded services as well as removed the `control-center` paid service.

The **A**nswer to this **Q**uestion provides the `three-broker` version.

```
---
version: '3'

# Single broker version.

networks:
  verilabs:
    name: verilabs
    external: false
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
         gateway: 192.168.10.1

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.20
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.21
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.22
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/kafka-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.23
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.2.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.24
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.2.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.25
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    privileged: true
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the `three-broker` version. You can run `sdiff(1)` on both files to spot the differences and pattern; then generalize to more brokers if needed.

`PS`: I added a `KAFKA_OPTS` to the `Zookeeper` service, which enables you to run `four-letter-word` commands to query it's status. (e.g. `ruok`, `stat`,...). Without that `whitelisting`, those commands would be rejected.

```
---
version: '3'

# Three broker version.

networks:
  verilabs:
    name: verilabs
    external: false
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
         gateway: 192.168.10.1

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.20
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      KAFKA_OPTS: "-Dzookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist=*"

  broker01:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    hostname: broker01
    container_name: broker01
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.21
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker01:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost

  broker02:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    hostname: broker02
    container_name: broker02
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29093:29092"
      - "9093:9092"
      - "9102:9101"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.22
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker02:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9093
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost

  broker03:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.0
    hostname: broker03
    container_name: broker03
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29094:29092"
      - "9094:9092"
      - "9103:9101"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.23
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker03:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9094
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - broker01
      - broker02
      - broker03
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.24
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker01:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/kafka-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - broker01
      - broker02
      - broker03
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.25
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker01:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR

  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.2.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    privileged: true
    depends_on:
      - broker01
      - broker02
      - broker03
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.26
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker01:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.2.0
    depends_on:
      - broker01
      - broker02
      - broker03
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    networks:
      verilabs:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.27
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    privileged: true
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker01:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
```

I hope this helps others.

Comment: Keep in mind - Multiple brokers on one host are competing for disk and memory resources, and therefore would be less optimal than only one. Also, it'd be easier just to use minikube and scale the brokers properly with a Kafka operator

Comment: Yes, of course. The above targets `development` and `self-instruction` audiences (some will want 3, 4, 5, 6, etc, brokers to test and interpolate). I could refactor the above to allow `docker-compose(1) scale [...]` (easy, too) to work (and have for other docker dev projects), but this is what I wanted to offer people (no `minikube` or anything else).

Comment: `docker-compose scale` doesn't completely work because the broker ID, ports and advertised listeners all need to be unique and consistent

Comment: But it does work. Different approaches require different configuration-effort, administration and technologies (tradeoffs - with each introducing their own problems, complexities and administration).. This post, by intent, offers a solution that requires not more than one config file and one technology.

Comment: In properties like `CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` why aren't all the brokers specified?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the existing answer has some typos in the ports as the brokers would not connect to each other for me even though zookeeper saw them (two in my case).

The following seems to have solved things for me.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.1
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker01:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.1
    hostname: broker01
    container_name: broker01
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker01:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost

  broker02:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.1
    hostname: broker02
    container_name: broker02
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "39092:39092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker02:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:39092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
```